# Emacs ERC buffer have no color

Tags: emacs

I don't know what happen, but when I reinstall the system (Xubuntu 14.04) with Emacs 24.3.1 and when I run erc, I got no colors. When I run ERC last time I have blue text now I got white. How can I check what's happened? I didn't run ERC for a while, maybe I change something in .emacs file.

Comment: Try placing the cursor on the section that previously had your `blue text` and type `C-u C-x =` and that will tell you whether there is anything at that location like font faces or overlays.  If there is nothing, well, then that's an issue.  If there is something, see what it is and whether it can be adjusted to your liking.

Comment: @lawlist I don't have any faces but I have them (and colors) when I run `emacs -q`

Comment: If it works correctly with a blank `.emacs` user configuration, then check your `*Messages*` buffer when Emacs loads with a full configuration. Maybe you'll get lucky and there will be an error message that will point you in the right direction.  If there is no error message, you may need to bisect your user-configuration file to find the error -- e.g., comment out the first half, then try commenting out the second-half, and so forth until you find the offending code.  If there is an error message, you can enable broader reporting with `(setq debug-on-error t)`.

Comment: @lawlist Thanks for your help, I ended up putting `(error "message")` in my .emacs and found the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the problem was `whitespace-mode` I've added erc-mode to the list where whitespace-mode is disabled:

```
(setq whitespace-mode-disable '(term-mode erc-mode))

(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (if (null (memql major-mode whitespace-mode-disable))
                (whitespace-mode))))
```